# Laravel 5 Lang::get() Replace

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems.

You can use the Lang :: get () in Laravel 5, I want to make a to replace characters.

resources/lang/en/messages.php

```
<?php
    return array(
    'test' => 'test message. :name',
```

views/top.blade.php

```
{!! App::setLocale('en') !!}
{!! Lang::get('messages.test', array('name' => 'Dayle')) !!}
```

However, it is an error.

```
ErrorException in Translator.php line 148:
Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Translation\Translator::Illuminate\Translation\{closure}(), called in /home/my-site/www/my-site/vendor/compiled.php on line 11547 and defined (View: /home/my-site/www/my-site/resources/views/top.blade.php)
```

Cause I do not know.

Do not people you know?

Comment: same problem here after composer update

Comment: i solved it by removing all cached files. (views, compiled etc)

Comment: had the same problem, in my case the problem was that I wrote [':name' => 'Dayle'] . I removed the colon before 'name' and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolve this issue by following the steps [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/lang-problem)

To summarize, try the following steps:

1. Delete the vendor/compiled.php and the storage/framework/compiled.php
2. Run `composer update` and if it didn't run automatically, run `php artisan optimise` to compile again.
3. Use double quotes in your messages.php file (e.g. `"title" => "Value in double qoutes"`)
4. Run `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis in message.php:
    'test' => 'test message. (:name)',

Also, looking at your error message, I think that 
    {!! App::setLocale('en') !!}
in your view is making a problem for some reason, so just delete it, it works without it, I tried.

Additionaly, add 
    use \Lang;
in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could try the recommended syntax -> `Lang::get('messages.test', ['name' => 'Dayle'])`?

update:

you could also try the helper function:

```
{{ trans('messages.test', array('name' => 'Dayle')) }}
```

and remove the , on the end of this line `test' => 'test message. :name',` in

also it would be better to `App::setLocale('en')` in your controller and not in the view but that's just best practices and probably not the cause of your issue.

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not heal. Is the same.

Comment: Heal not. Is the same.

Comment: how does the rest of resources/lang/en/messages.php look?

Comment: @limonte you are right, there is no difference, just wanted to rule out a blade specific issue

Comment: only 'test' => 'test message. :name', .